# SQlite select top N rows from the table for each item

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a  table like below and I am trying to select top 2 rows of each stream by createdDate.

```
    ID  Name    createdDate(string)
76  Stream1 2018-10-19T00:00:00
76  Stream1 2018-10-18T00:00:00 
76  Stream1 2018-10-17T00:00:00  
70  Stream2 2018-10-17T00:00:00 
70  Stream2 2018-10-03T00:00:00 
70  Stream2 2018-09-22T00:00:00 
21  Stream3 2018-09-21T00:00:00
21  Stream3 2018-09-20T00:00:00 
21  Stream3 2018-08-21T00:00:00
```

and the output looks like below, how do I build a query for this

```
76  Stream1 2018-10-19T00:00:00
76  Stream1 2018-10-18T00:00:00 
70  Stream2 2018-10-17T00:00:00 
70  Stream2 2018-10-03T00:00:00 
21  Stream3 2018-09-21T00:00:00
21  Stream3 2018-09-20T00:00:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from SQLite 3.25 you could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name
                      ORDER BY CAST(createdDate AS DATE) DESC) AS rn
  FROM tab
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by cast(createdDate as date) desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq <= 2;
```